# integrate native calendar in my app on ipad?

Tags: ios, ipad, calendar, uikit, native

How to integrate native calendar (IPad) for month and week in UIKit and change its colors?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known library for that https://github.com/klazuka/Kal
Or you could use this one: https://github.com/kovpas/PMCalendar

Comment: the first link is for iphone, and second is modal... i need fully screen calendar as ipad native calendar...

Answer (score -1):

The most interesting with calendars is that you can also sync reminders with your iPad, iPhone and laptop. Beesy is a practical tool for appointments (http://www.beesapps.com/features-beesy/ios-reminders-sync-beesy/).

Sofye.